# Are cross-controller outlets with the storyboard paradigm possible?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, interface-builder, storyboard

For a small Cocoa Touch application for the iPhone I would like to use the interface builder as lightweight dependency injection.

To accomplish this, I would either need to create a "global" object that does not belong to a view controller or alternatively an object that belongs to the root view controller and is injected as an outlet.

I can not able to realize any of the above mentioned methods? Are they possible and if yes, how?